# Processing Outlook .msg messages on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, outlook, aws-sdk

I do have Outlook message in .msg file (Microsoft OLE Structured Storage databases) and need to extract data from message.
Is there any AWS service which could help? For example I send request to API and as response receive message in JSON format incl attachments?

Similar way as https://pypi.org/project/msg-parser/ works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is none that serve the specific purpose of parsing Outlook .msg and return it's content.

You can, however, deploy the library you mentioned (or another one) on Lambda - API Gateway and get the result you desired for minimal cost

Comment: Yep, it looks really no shortcut here, in the end I've used msgconvert